# webAPI communication in python: Requested route has not been mapped in spark

Tags: python, json, spark-java, web-api-testing

I'm trying to communicate with a server (program controlling robots) via webAPI which expects JSON Files. I tried to realize this with the following Python Code, but I always get the Error:

The requested route [/v1/TransportOrders/Order-0001] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [*/*]

Does anybody know what causes the error or how to fix it?
Let me know if you need any further details.
Thanks

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json


url = 'http://localhost:55200/v1/TransportOrders/Order-0001'
# headers= {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
transportOrders = {
  "deadline": "2019-03-07T06:42:40.396Z",
  "intendedVehicle": "Vehicle-0001",
  "destinations": [
    {
      "locationName": "Location-0001",
      "operation": "NOTHING",
    }
  ]
}
resp = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(transportOrders))
print 'data sent'
if resp.status_code != 200:
    print 'error accured transmitting data'
    print resp.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

> The requested route [/v1/TransportOrders/Order-0001] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [/]

This is the default "404" message from SparkJava. You should double-check in the server API documentation that you are calling the right end point, at the right path with the right parameters and headers - and the right server, for that matter.